# Sequential Lorentz transformation on an accelerating frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time-dilation

A rocket takes off from Earth and increases its speed by 0.001 **c** every second. When the speed reaches 0.99 **c**, it decreases its speed by 0.001 **c** every second until its speed returns to 0.

Then, it turns around and increases its speed by 0.001 **c** every second back towards the Earth. When it reaches 0.99 **c** in this homeward direction, it decreases its speed by 0.001 **c** and stops exactly when it reaches Earth.

By applying Lorentz transformation every second to switch into the rocket's frame,

$$x'=\gamma(x-vt)$$
$$t'=\gamma\left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$$

[image]

the Earth clock is found to have ticked significantly more (3958) than the rocket clock (3136).

My questions are:

1. Can this "discrete integration" method be used to find the Lorentz transform of an *accelerating frame of reference*, by making t extremely small (eg. 0.00000000001 second) and setting a different v for each small time interval, and applying the Lorentz transform piecewise?
2. It does not make practical sense that the rocket can accelerate to 0.99 **c** in 2000 seconds. But this is nowhere encoded into Lorentz transformation. *Which part of special relativity prohibits accelerating beyond the speed of light?*

Comment: A comment to the second question. Notice that the magnitude of the four velocity is a constant $U^{\mu}U_{\mu}=c^2$, so no component can ever go  above $c$

Comment: Comment to first question, you would not do the problem like this in practice, although it is a good teaching exercise (for the maths at least!).  The "correct" way is to perform the integration analytically, leading to the hyperbolic equations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(special_relativity)#Curved_world_lines

Answer (score 1):

> By applying Lorentz transformation every second to switch into the rocket's frame

What you are switching into is not the rocket's frame. The rocket is non-inertial so its frame is also non-inertial. What you are switching to is called the momentarily co-moving inertial frame (MCIF). It is important to distinguish the MCIF from the rocket's frame since the MCIF is inertial and the rocket's frame is not.

> Can this "discrete integration" method be used to find the Lorentz transform of an accelerating frame of reference, by making t extremely small (eg. 0.00000000001 second) and setting a different v for each small time interval, and applying the Lorentz transform piecewise?

No. There is no such thing as the Lorentz transform of an accelerating frame of reference. The Lorentz transform is the transform between inertial frames and an accelerating frame is not inertial.

You can, of course, construct a non-inertial frame for the accelerating rocket by using the simultaneity defined by each MCIF. However, that runs into some [well-known problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0104077), so other methods of constructing non-inertial frames are typically preferable (e.g. [radar coordinates](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0104077), or [Fermi coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates))

> It does not make practical sense that the rocket can accelerate to 0.99 c in 2000 seconds. But this is nowhere encoded into Lorentz transformation. Which part of special relativity prohibits accelerating beyond the speed of light?

It is actually encoded into the Lorentz transform. The composition of $n$ Lorentz transforms, each of velocity $\delta \beta \ c$ is not the same as one Lorentz transform of velocity $v= \beta \ c = n \ \delta \beta \ c$. The actual formula is $$\beta=\sqrt{1-\frac{4 \left( 1-\delta \beta^2 \right)^n}{\left( \left( 1-\delta \beta \right)^n + \left( 1+ \delta \beta\right)^n \right)^2}}$$

[image: Total boost from n small boosts]

This is probably more easily understood from the [velocity addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula). No matter how many times you add a small velocity you never get a total velocity that exceeds $c$

Comment: thank you vm! My rocket could get to 0.99 **c** because i could manually input a = 0.01 **c** continuously by hand. Is there a way using only the Lorentz transformation to input into the model a fixed thrust per second (eg. from rocket fuel), then having the resulting acceleration naturally drop exponentially as we approach the speed of light?

Comment: @James use the formula I provided, which is derived directly from the Lorentz transform. If $\delta \beta=0.01$ then for $n=99$ you get $0.757$ not $0.99$. It already naturally drops as you approach the speed of light.

Comment: thank you. this is akin to chain throwing a rock every second at speed v=0.01 **c** with respect to the previous rock, all the while measuring the latest rock speed from the stationary t=0 frame?

Comment: ... or better chain throw rocket *fuel* every second from the rocket's back exhaust, then use conservation of momentum to get the forward velocity change of the reduced rocket mass, then use this velocity number as the latest velocity for the new boost.

Comment: @James yes, it sounds like you have the idea